# ios find all saved files

Tags: iphone, ios, filepath

My app downloads a number of jpegs every now and again. All the jpeg file names are saved in the format of "hmof-*.jpg Is there a way that I can remove all files that don't start with the prefix of "hmof-" ?

I'll obviously need to do this in a loop, but I'm not sure what to loop through.

Comment: Remove them from what?  An array, a set, a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this...

```
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self BEGINSWITH 'hmof-')"];
    NSArray *notHMOF = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

You can delete files using:

```
for (int i=0; i<[notHMOF count]; i++) 
{       
    [fm removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",bundleRoot,[notHMOF objectAtIndex:i]] error:nil];
}
```

**EDIT:** That works..